# How to make Electron tray menu icon sensitive to macos menu bar colour changes in macos?

Tags: electron, themes, trayicon

I understand that right now we can use nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors to tell if the user has changed from light to dark mode and vice versa. However, I understand that the menu bar colour is a function of more than just the mode. For instance, in light mode, my menu bar changes to use dark mode colours for other menu bar icons around 630pm local time. How do I make my tray icon sensitive to such a change as well?

I understand that a possible solution would be to use template images but I would like to have a red badge on my icon as well but template images only consist of black and white. The documentation here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image#template-image mentions that we should mix template images with other content to create the desired final appearance. Are there examples of how that is done?

I tried nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors but it didn't take the time of day into consideration? I still get a light themed image when the rest of the menu bar icons flipped to use a dark themed image.